# 403 error with google geolocation api in c#

Tags: c#, api, google-maps

I am trying to use google maps geolocation api (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro) in c# (.net 4.6.1).  I have setup a server key and enabled the Google Maps Geolocation API in the api manager.  Here is my code:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate", new { key = "keyvalue" });
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I get a 403 error. Here is the complete response:

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [{
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
        "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
        "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
    }],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
}
```

}

I know they key value is correct and I know I have enabled the api. I also know that I haven't reached the daily limit, because the google console lists my usage as zero for the day. Does anyone see an issue with my code or have any other suggestions?  I must be incorrectly sending the key, but I don't know where the error is in my code.

**Update**

The correct code is:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=keyvalue", "" );
    //Or client.PostAsync could be used this way:
    //var response = await client.PostAsync("https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=keyvalue", new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I was passing the key as a json object instead of putting the key in the url.

Comment: As the error response suggests that you are exceeding unauthenticated use, are your sure that your request sends the key correctly?

Comment: I am sure that I have the correct key, but I don't know how to confirm that the key is being correctly sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the key as a parameter to the URL

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=keyValue
```